# python - getting a specific number of results with SQLAlchemy for page

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database with user posts stored in it. Now I want my flask app to display n posts per page, but the problem is, that posts might be deleted at some point.
My basic query is:

```
start = (page-1) * n 
postlist = Posts.query.filter(Posts.id > start).limit(n).all()
```

this returns n posts beginning at start. This works well, except that getting start for pages other than 1 doesn't work properly if there are deleted posts.
Assume posts 5 and 7 are deleted, page 1 will show posts 1-12, page 2 will show posts 11-20 and so on, meaning some posts will be shown on multiple pages. This problem would snowball hard for larger databases.

So, I thought of two ways to mitigate that problem, though I'm not fond of either of those.

a) instead of getting n posts, we get the posts from start to start+n:

```
start = (page-1) * n
end = start + n
postlist = Posts.query.filter(Posts.id > start).filter(Posts.id <= (start+n)).all()
```

This works, but I'm obviously not getting n results per page. Worst case scenario, there will be pages which are completely empty. Several of them. One after another. So, another option would b):

```
postlist = Posts.query.filter(Posts.id > start).limit(n).all()
end = postlist[-1].id
```

and then using end as the start for the next page. But: I'd have to provide the new value for start via GET (which looks ugly), and visiting a specific page via its generic url (/posts/page/#) would yield different results than using the previous / next links which would supply the ?start=# argument via url.

If anyone knows of a way around this problem, that'd be swell; thanks in advance.

Comment: The `BaseQuery` object in `Flask-SQLAlchemy` has a method named [`paginate`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) which can help you.

Comment: @stamaimer
thanks, didn't know about that method, this really helped to fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use of below approaches to get the results

using **offset and limit** by using page and count variables

```
page = kwargs.pop('page', None)
count = kwargs.pop('count', None)
page = page * count
postlist = Posts.query.filter(Posts.id.desc()).offset(page).limit(count).all()
```

another method to use **sqlalchemy Paginator**

```
from sqlalchemy_paginator import Paginator
page_size = 20
postlist_obj = Posts.query.filter(Posts.id.desc())
pagination = Paginator(postlist_obj,page_size)
```

Once you got the pagination object then you can access parameters like below depending on page number

```
page_number = 1
page = paginator.page(page_number)
total_pages=paginator.total_pages
total_records_count=paginator.page(paginator.total_pages).end_index
record)list = page.object_list
```

Comment: Thank you, the offset and limit way works well, though I decided to use the pagination method via sqlalchemy's paginate function as mentioned by stamaimer.
The sqlalchemy_paginator didn't work for me, as it attempts to import a class "exceptions" which seems to be part of Django, which I am not using. Still, thanks for mentioning it, that really got me to read into the built-in pagination methods.